# Can't spot my error in calculating 3D Parametric Arc Length

Tags: calculus, parametric, arc-length

**We're asked to find a function s(t), for the arc length of a curve centered at point t=0, as a function of t.
The function is as follows...**

$\gamma (t) =e^t i + \sqrt{2} tj-e^{-t}k$

**My work is as follows...**

$\gamma '(t) =e^t i + \sqrt{2} j+e^{-t}k$

$s(t)=\int_{-t}^{+t} \sqrt{(e^x)^2+(\sqrt{2})^2+(e^{-x})^2} \,dx$

$s(t)=\int_{-t}^{+t} \sqrt{e^{2x}+2+e^{-2x}} \,dx$

...Used computer to compute integral(side question: what method could be used to integrate by hand)...

$s(t)=e^x-e^{-x} \Big|_{-t}^{+t}$

$s(t)=e^t-e^{-t}-(e^{-t}-e^t)$

**Final Answer:** $s(t)=2e^t-2e^{-t}$

However, my answer is marked as incorrect. I don't believe there's something wrong with the calculating bits, cause if I graph my answer vs the computer calculating the whole thing, I get the same line-
[Picture Of Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgS2o.png). So it leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong in the setup. Pretty sure the arc length equation is fine. So the only thing I can think of is I'm interpreting the "centered at point t=0" incorrectly?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the exact question, but yes perhaps your integral should be from $\int_0^t (\cdots) \,dx $ instead of $\int_{-t}^t (\cdots) \,dx$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> "Using a computer to integrate" is conceivably grounds for marking the answer wrong. By analogy, if you were in a golf course (as it were, i.e., a course on golf) and you "solved" a hole by carrying the ball to the green and dropping it in the cup, you might not get credit....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I suspect they intended to say “starting at $t=0$” and you interpreted their “centered at” literally. (Is this a question written in English or a translation?)

To answer your other question, you should recognize the perfect square under the square root. You will probably encounter a number of them.

Comment: Yep, talking half of my equation was correct! The exact wording was "centered at point t=0".  And I see, so it just becomes sqrt[(e^x+e^-x)^2] then you just go from there.